# it is sending empty array to mongo DB ,tried all the insertion methods?

Tags: node.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Accept = require('../models/acceptrequeststable');
const BlockMainTable = require('../models/blocks');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.requestinsert = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const requests = req.body; // Assuming req.body is an array of request objects

    const newRequests = await Accept.create(requests);
    console.log(res);
    res.status(200).json({
      data: newRequests,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Internal server error',
    });
  }
};
```

> have tried all possible methods to send that data to mongodb still it is sending null that data comming till node js after that it is not getting inserted in the mongo dB .i have tried create,insertmany,createcollection function still no use all the inserton are empty

Comment: I think you are not passing the correct data type. Please log your requests variable. Is it the same as your expectation?